# Bash script runs more than one times. Dont know why

Tags: 20.04, bash, lubuntu, cron, log

I have a really simple bash script which runs as cron job every minute. It makes a log to file. Everything works fine but there is one weird thing. The script make more than one logs at the same time. I dont understand how is it possible. Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash


# -c returns number of lines in grep result
isActive=$(systemctl status elasticsearch | grep "active (running)" -c)

if (( $isActive == 0 )) 
then

  systemctl start elasticsearch
  
  timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
  touch /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start.log
  echo "${timestamp} Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active." >> /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start.log

fi
```

The cron job

```
* * * * * bash /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh
```

The log file looks like

```
2021-07-13 16-17-45 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-17-45 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-17-45 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-17-45 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-20-15 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-20-15 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-20-15 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-23-11 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-26-36 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-26-36 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-26-36 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-33-13 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-33-13 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-33-13 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-33-13 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-33-25 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-34-10 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-35-10 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-40-39 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-40-39 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-40-39 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-40-39 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-40-39 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-41-13 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
2021-07-13 16-42-07 Elasticsearch service has to be restarted by /root/custom-scripts/elasticsearch/start-elasticsearch.sh because service status was not active.
```

Is there somebody who can explain it to me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but systemctl has an `is-active` action that you can test directly ex. `if systemctl --quiet is-active elasticsearch; then ...`

Comment: Thanks I did not know about it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might explain what you're seeing is if the elasticsearch.service file has an `ExecStartPre` or `ExecStartPost` that (directly or indirectly) invokes the same script

Comment: Dont understand it. Elasticsearch does not know about the script.

Comment: The reason is I did not heart about Restart=on-failure and the second is the log file which shows me the fail cases.

Comment: Uf did not heart.... Sorry Mrs. English.

Comment: Dont know about systemd.timer. I would like to know why this happened with standard cron job. I am not an Linux expert. I need to manage it on "my level". Which should work.

Comment: Add `$$` to your message to show the PID of the process, for debugging

Answer (score 0):

I would check a couple of things:

1. Are there two or more cron processes running? You can check with ps -ef|grep cron
2. Is there anything in /etc/cron.d that is calling this script? Seems unlikely, but won't hurt to check.